# IE Kiosk Mode on touchscreen - disable swipe

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, kiosk

I have tablets running Windows 8 RT/Full and when they boot up they go straight into Internet Explorer Kiosk mode (iexplore -k).

This is fine on a normal PC, however on a tablet device users are still able to swipe from the side of the screen to access the start menu.

Is there any way to stop users from using the operating-system swipe gestures during Kiosk mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to lockdown a Microsoft Surface RT in kiosk mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/562464/is-it-possible-to-lockdown-a-microsoft-surface-rt-in-kiosk-mode)

Comment: Thanks @Karan. This particular post didn't show up as a preview whilst creating this. The question still stands however.. both aren't answered :(

Comment: This one might help: [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop).

Comment: @iamwpj: I don't know of any WinRT devices with a Synaptics touchpad.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: As one of the answers on that thread states, guess you'll have to wait for Win8.1, whose Preview is now just 5 days or so away.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some serious time locking down Dell Windows 8 Tablets for browser Kiosks and can tell you that the best way I have found to disable the swipe is to replace the explorer shell under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\Shell

and put in the path to IE, Firefox, or Chrome.  This is an old school way to go about it, but it still works and you don't have to throw a bunch of addons at the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Windows Embedded 8 Standard or Windows Embedded 8.1 you will have embedded features available to easily disable swipe gestures.